# Spring 4.4.3 and Quartz 2.2.1 - rg.quartz.ObjectAlreadyExistsException: Unable to store Job because one already exists with this identification

Tags: spring, quartz

I have the need occasionally to update a Trigger on a Job.
My triggers only fire once, and the fire date may vary.

So I have a JobManager which manages this situation. The idea was to check if a given jobDetail already exists, then delete it and create a new one, but i'm getting strange behavior and this exception.

So my controller calls `jobManager.createJob(interruttore, richiesta);` which is:

```
public void createJob(Interruttore interruttore, Date richiesta) throws SchedulerException {

        JobDetail jobDetail = createJobDetail(interruttore);

        createOrUpdateScheduledJobs(interruttore, jobDetail, richiesta);
    }
```

this is createJob

```
public JobDetail createJobDetail(Interruttore interruttore) throws SchedulerException {
        if (scheduler.getScheduler().checkExists(JobKey.jobKey("JobDetail" + interruttore.getNomeInterruttore()))) {
            logger.debug("jobDetail already present, delete it");scheduler.getScheduler().deleteJob(JobKey.jobKey("JobDetail" + interruttore.getNomeInterruttore()));
        } 
        logger.debug("Il jobDetail non esiste, lo creo");
        JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactoryBean = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
        jobDetailFactoryBean.setJobClass(TimeoutJob.class);
        jobDetailFactoryBean.setName("JobDetail" + interruttore.getNomeInterruttore());
        jobDetailFactoryBean.setGroup("timeoutJobDetail");
        jobDetailFactoryBean.setDescription("Job for timeout");
        jobDetailFactoryBean.setDurability(true);

        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        map.put("idInterruttore", interruttore.getIdInterruttore());
        jobDetailFactoryBean.setJobDataAsMap(map);
        jobDetailFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        logger.debug("JobDetail is " + jobDetailFactoryBean.toString());

        return jobDetailFactoryBean.getObject();

    }
```

and `createOrUpdateScheduledJobs(interruttore, jobDetail, richiesta);` is the following

```
public void createOrUpdateScheduledJobs(Interruttore interruttore, JobDetail jobDetail,
            Date richiesta) throws SchedulerException {


        // check if trigger exists
        boolean triggerExist = scheduler.getObject().checkExists(
                TriggerKey.triggerKey("myTrigger" + interruttore.getNomeInterruttore(), "timeoutTriggers"));
        logger.debug("Trigger exists? :" + triggerExist);

        if (triggerExist) { //replace trigger and reschedule job

            SimpleTrigger oldTrigger = (SimpleTrigger) scheduler.getScheduler().getTrigger(
                    TriggerKey.triggerKey("myTrigger" + interruttore.getNomeInterruttore(), "timeoutTriggers"));
            TriggerBuilder<SimpleTrigger> tb = oldTrigger.getTriggerBuilder();
            SimpleTrigger newTrigger = tb.startAt(richiesta).build();
            scheduler.getScheduler().rescheduleJob(((SimpleTrigger) oldTrigger).getKey(), newTrigger);
            logger.debug("new Trigger with firetime " + newTrigger.getNextFireTime());

        } else { // create a new one
            // creo il trigger e lo schedulo il job
            SimpleTriggerFactoryBean trigger = new SimpleTriggerFactoryBean();
            trigger.setName("myTrigger" + interruttore.getNomeInterruttore());
            trigger.setGroup("timeoutTriggers");
            trigger.setJobDetail(jobDetail.getObject());
            trigger.setStartTime(richiesta);
            trigger.setRepeatCount(0);
            trigger.afterPropertiesSet();
            try {
                scheduler.getScheduler().scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger.getObject());
            } catch (SchedulerException e) {
                logger.error("Errore: ", e);
            }
            logger.debug("Trigger object is :" + trigger.getObject());
        }

    }
```

When i launch the application, everything goes right, then the second time my controller call the method i'm getting the exception

```
org.quartz.ObjectAlreadyExistsException: Unable to store Job : 'timeoutJobDetail.JobDetailZona -2A', because one already exists with this identification.
```

The method to create the new jobDetail does not find a previous jobDetail instance to delete, but when creating a new one, it finds it exist indeed...

Answer (score 0):

TriggerKey and JobKey consist of both Name and Group.

So you need to specify Group in your TriggerKey and JobKey same as your SimpleTriggerFactoryBean and JobDetailFactoryBean.

Sorry, I haven't checked it correctly but when I change JobKey and TriggerKey. Scheduler.deleteJob() method is called at createJobDetail method in the second time.